# How do I generate and set the locale using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am looking for an idempotent ansible role/task to ensure a certain locale (like en_US.UTF-8) is set as default. It should generate the locale (only if necessary) and set it as a default (also only if necessary).

For the first part I'd register the output of `locale -a | grep "{{ locale_name }}"` and generate if needed.

For the second part I'm wondering if running update-locale every time is good enough because that command itself is idempotent anyway.

Comment: For the first part see [`locale_gen`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/locale_gen_module.html). For the second, what is update-locale? That's not the way to set the locale on a modern Linux system (and I can't even find it!), `localectl` is.

Comment: `update-locale` is the command that works on all Debian-family systems. It does the same as localectl and the question remains the same (for the second part). :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `localectl` command from @mniess answer will always report as "changed" even if the new values are the equal to the current ones. Here's what I personally ended up to set both `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` and solve that issue:

```yaml
- name: Ensure localisation files for '{{ config_system_locale }}' are available
  locale_gen:
    name: "{{ config_system_locale }}"
    state: present

- name: Ensure localisation files for '{{ config_system_language }}' are available
  locale_gen:
    name: "{{ config_system_language }}"
    state: present

- name: Get current locale and language configuration
  command: localectl status
  register: locale_status
  changed_when: false

- name: Parse 'LANG' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_lang: "{{ locale_status.stdout | regex_search('LANG=([^\n]+)', '\\1') | first }}"

- name: Parse 'LANGUAGE' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_language: "{{ locale_status.stdout | regex_search('LANGUAGE=([^\n]+)', '\\1') | default([locale_lang], true) | first }}"

- name: Configure locale to '{{ config_system_locale }}' and language to '{{ config_system_language }}'
  become: yes
  command: localectl set-locale LANG={{ config_system_locale }} LANGUAGE={{ config_system_language }}
  changed_when: locale_lang != config_system_locale or locale_language != config_system_language
```

Also, this what I have at `group_vars/main.yml`:

```yaml
config_system_locale: 'pt_PT.UTF-8'
config_system_language: 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: Thanks! You could also change `changed_when:` to `when:` on the last line to skip that command altogether when the locale is already set correctly.

Comment: Note: Won't work on RHEL/CentOS

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
- name: Ensure the locale exists
  locale_gen:
    name: en_US.UTF-8
    state: present
- name: set as default locale
  command: localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Note: At least on Ubuntu setting `LC_ALL` with the `localectl set-locale` command fails with the following error: `Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data.`

Comment: @ToFi locale data needs to be installed for this to work (e.g. language-pack-*).

Comment: @mniess I install `language-pack-*` and it din't work, it only works if I removed the `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

While rfgamaral's answer is great, it only works in Debian because [the `locale_gen` community module does not support RHEL](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44708). To support both RHEL/CentOS *and* Debian, try the following:

```
- name: check if locale exists
  shell: "locale -a | grep -i {{ config_system_locale | regex_replace('-', '') | quote }}"
  register: found_locale
  changed_when: no
  failed_when: no

- name: create locale
  command: "localedef -i {{ config_system_locale | regex_replace('(.*)\\..*', '\\1') | quote }} -f {{ config_system_locale | regex_replace('.*\\.(.*)', '\\1') | quote }} {{ config_system_locale | quote }}"
  when: not ansible_check_mode and found_locale.rc != 0

- name: check if language exists
  shell: "locale -a | grep -i {{ config_system_language | regex_replace('-', '') | quote }}"
  register: found_language
  changed_when: no
  failed_when: no

- name: create language
  command: "localedef -i {{ config_system_language | regex_replace('(.*)\\..*', '\\1') | quote }} -f {{ config_system_language | regex_replace('.*\\.(.*)', '\\1') | quote }} {{ config_system_language | quote }}"
  when: not ansible_check_mode and found_language.rc != 0

- name: Get current locale and language configuration
  command: localectl status
  register: locale_status
  changed_when: false

- name: Parse 'LANG' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_lang: "{{ locale_status.stdout | regex_search('LANG=([^\n]+)', '\\1') | first }}"

- name: Parse 'LANGUAGE' from current locale and language configuration
  set_fact:
    locale_language: "{{ locale_status.stdout | regex_search('LANGUAGE=([^\n]+)', '\\1') | default([locale_lang], true) | first }}"

- name: Configure locale to '{{ config_system_locale }}' and language to '{{ config_system_language }}'
  command: localectl set-locale LANG={{ config_system_locale }} LANGUAGE={{ config_system_language }}
  changed_when: locale_lang != config_system_locale or locale_language != config_system_language
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a fedora system and ended up with a solution that works exclusively with `localectl`:

playbook:

```yaml
- name: Apply localectl settings
  tags:
      - system
      - localectl
  block:
      - name: Import localectl vars
        ansible.builtin.include_vars: localectl/vars.yml

      - name: Set localectl setting
        ansible.builtin.include_tasks: localectl/_tasks.yml
        loop: "{{ localectl_settings }}"
        loop_control:
            label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

localectl/vars.yml:

```yaml
localectl_settings:
    - name: language
      value: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
      regex: "System Locale: "
      command: set-locale

    - name: keymap
      value: euro
      regex: "VC Keymap: "
      command: set-keymap

    - name: x11 layout
      value: eu
      regex: "X11 Layout: "
      command: set-x11-keymap
```

localectl/_tasks.yml:

```yaml
---
- name: Set localectl settings
  become: true
  tags:
      - system
      - localectl
  block:
      - name: Get status of localectl {{ item.name }}
        ansible.builtin.shell:
            cmd: localectl status | grep -E "{{ item.regex }}{{ item.value }}"
        register: result_locale_status
        failed_when: false
        changed_when: false

      - name: Set localectl setting
        ansible.builtin.command:
            cmd: "{{ localectl_command }}"
        when: result_locale_status.rc == 1
        loop_control:
            loop_var: localectl_command
        loop:
            - "localectl {{ item.command }} {{ item.value }}"
```